# Is it possible to infect a monitor via HDMI plus Ethernet

Tags: malware, virus, ports

I caught a virus because of an exe file I downloaded to my computer last week. I am replacing my modem, graphics card, motherboard, processor, ssd and ram components with new ones. What are the chances that my monitors are infected? My two monitors were connected to my computer via HDMI ethernet cable. How do I secure my monitors or do I need to replace them?

Comment: Why are you replacing all that?

Comment: They drained my metamask wallet, now I am too scared. I don’t want to leave it to any chance. Now the only possibility is my monitors. Do you think it is a risk?

Comment: I think you are overreacting. There is a difference between a car thief and an art thief and a con artist. The malware that would infect hardware is very different from malware that is designed to steal from a wallet.

Comment: Yes, I know I am overreacting but I really don’t want this to happen to me again. I need an answer if they have the control of my system, are they able to infect my monitors? Also it is not just my wallet, my gmail, discord, everything.

Comment: The links above explain